# Decode json and count array equal

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to count how many arrays are equal after a decode json.

```
    {
      "IP": [
             {

                 "C_P": "US",
                 "C_L": "United States"

              },
              {

                  "C_P": "IT",
                  "C_L": "ITALY"

              },              
              {

                  "C_P": "US",
                  "C_L": "United States"

              },              
              {

                   "C_P": "CO",
                   "C_L": "Colombia"

              },              
              {

                    "C_P": "US",
                    "C_L": "United States"

              }

        ]
    }
```

Using a process loop that counts the array "C_P", the result should be:

```
 3: US
 1: IT
 1: CO
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $result = json_decode($json);

    $countArray = array();
    foreach ($result as $key => $element) {
        foreach ($element as $cp)
            if (isset($countArray[$cp->C_P]))
                $countArray[$cp->C_P] ++;
            else
                $countArray[$cp->C_P] = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives me an error ... "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach ()"  
$data = file_get_contents('cerca_ip.php');
$result = json_decode($data);

Comment: Please check it with your given String as $data

Comment: yes, I used curl instead of file_get_contents. Forgive me for my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
$array = (array)json_decode($a, true);
$index  = array();
foreach ($array['IP'] as $key => $value){
    unset($value['C_L']);
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
        if (array_key_exists($value2, $index)){
           $index[$value2]++;
        } else {
            $index[$value2] = 1;
        }
    }
}
print_r($index);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [US] => 3
    [IT] => 1
    [CO] => 1
)
```